# Vertical columns using Views Responsive Grid module

Tags: views

I have created a view that groups items by type.  The output is in responsive columns, accomplished using the Views Responsive Grid module.  However, the items should be listed vertically, but they are being listed horizontally regardless of what I set the Alignment to in Style Options.

Has anybody found a fix for this?

Comment: Have you read this part on the module's page: You'll need to understand that the the module won't provide any default styling to the grid so you may think it's not working, this is by design. In order for the columns to work...

Comment: I read that and had added the necessary classes that were mentioned.  However, once I added more styling to get the headers lined up correctly, I realized that the columns were created within the groups instead of the items listed below each header then the columns created.